# Question regarding combining two independent clauses using colons

Tags: colons

After doing research on the proper way of combining two independent clauses using colons, I wanted to confirm that the examples below are using them correctly.

From my research, the second independent clause should interpret or amplify the first.

I'd appreciate any feedback on this topic.

Example 1:

- Ask yourself why you haven't gained muscle: is it because you haven't been to the gym?

Example 2:

- The chair is blue: it was painted by a famous artist who wanted to represent the sky.

Example 3:

- Tell me why you're mad: I'm assuming it's because I didn't call you.

--

Also, I've read that capitalizing the letter after the colon is a style choice unless we're discussing proper nouns, lists, or sentence fragments. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to all your questions.

Here is the relevant discussion from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 1743; note that [*asyndetic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asyndeton) means that the coordination in question does not use an explicit coordinator such as *and,* *but,* etc.):

> **Asyndetic combinations of main clauses**
>
> …
>
> ■ **Colon**
>
> [18]  i  *Roosevelt was not a socialist: his
> solution was not to eliminate capital, but to
>
>              tame and regulate
> it so that it could coexist harmoniously with labour.*
>         ii  *He told
> us his preference: Jan would take Spanish; Betty would take
> French.*
>        iii  *The rules
> were clear: they were not allowed to speak to the committee
> directly.*
>        iv  *Brown pointed
> out the costs to the community on the radio last night, and
>
>             McReady mentioned
> the political consequence in this morning's paper: the bill
>
>              will cost
> the taxpayers more
> than $100,000 in the first year, and may be seen
>
>              as giving the
> Republicans an unfair electoral
> advantage.*
>
> The colon, we have seen, is not used in syndetic coordination, and in
> aysndetic combinations it indicates an elaborative rather than
> coordinative interpretation. What it elaborates on may be a whole
> clause, as in [i], or a smaller element, such as *his preference* in
> [ii] or the non-final NP *the rules* in [iii]; indeed, there may be
> more than one such item, as in [iv], where the clause following the
> colon elaborates on both *the costs* and *the political consequence.*
>
> Like the comma and semicolon, the colon can separate a
> positive-negative sequence, where the first clause contains *not +
> only/simply/merely/just:*
>
> [19] *The Romans built not only the Fort of Othona: they had a pharos,
> or lighthouse,
>
>          on Mersea.*
>
> This does not invalidate our statement that the colon cannot be used
> to separate clauses in a coordinative relation. It is, rather, that
> the elaboration relation makes perfect sense in this context: the
> second clause provides an explanation or demonstration of what is said
> in the first clause. Note, then, that it would be quite impossible to
> insert *but* after the colon.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth Sorry, can you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, indeed. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: This augments the previous analyses. It might be good if the threads were merged: that takes superpowers. [Comment on possible course of action; I'm hoping the colon licenses the non-conditional usage coming later.]